# Could we prevent users' cursor turn into selection tool with css?

Tags: css

With `user-select: none` we are able to easily prevent user from selecting text in undesired areas like menu, but the browser cursor will still turn into selection tool, suggesting it is selectable. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Better yet, can we manipulate the cursor into link indicator?

Comment: You can create custom cursors, but why do you even want to stop people from selecting text in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pointer-events: none` to avoid having the cursor turning selection tool. I am unaware if you can turn the cursor into link indicator with css.

Comment: I just realized I can use `cursor:pointer ` to change cursor type. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think `cursor: pointer` would be the CSS declaration you’re looking for. Add that to the rules you have `user-select: none` applied to.

More info about `cursor` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Answer (score 0):

> Better yet, can we manipulate the cursor into link indicator?

This part of the question can be done with `cursor: pointer`.